# Strange IP settings issue

Tags: windows, ip, dhcp

Friend of mine is having a puzzling issue I've not come across before.

Windows Vista box, logs into an SBS2003 domain controller @ 192.168.1.50.

The first time the issue popped up (about two months ago) he said he didn't have Internet access. Sure enough, when I tried to go to www.google.com, it didn't. Pinging the 1.50 box was successful, so I figured it was a DNS issue. When I went into the IPv4 settings, however, the static IP address was there (as I had set it months earlier), and the "get DNS manually" box was checked but the DNS addresses were blank. I know they HAD been there since it was me who put them there in the first place months earlier. I set them back to what they had been, searched around the interwebs a bit, shot a line or two out in IRC, but nothing. Life went on...

This morning he called again -- no Internet access. This time I went directly to IPv4 settings, and they were set to DHCP. That was odd -- I had left it static last time (see above), and no one had touched it in the meanwhile.

There is not enough knowledge in his environment to change this information, and the PC is not accessible to anyone else, so I'm wondering if anyone has ever come across this phenomenon. Either static DNS info getting blanked out, or the whole thing being changed from static to DHCP.

Box has been regularly checked for virus/malware/etc infections with negative results.

Would very much appreciate any ideas from the well of knowledge.

Thanks!

Comment: My Guess: Temporary network problem happens, user is an Admin on the computer, they are offered Troubleshooting button, they hit it, Windows resets network stack and sets it to DHCP while trying to repair the problem.

Comment: Plausible -- but you'd agree that there would have to be SOME sort of human interaction, right? IOW, neither of the two scenarios would happen on their own, right?